# method not allowed:POST

Tags: django, forms

my code show errors:

```
method not allowed: POST 
method not allowed: /home/
```

while running the server
I couldn't find where the error is and whenever I click search in my html form it again reidirects me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/
here is my app's  view.py

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class ResultPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'results.html'

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        MYSearch = Searchform(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            MYSearch = Searchform()

    return render(request, 'results.html',{"MYSearch":MYSearch})
```

forms.py

```
class Searchform(forms.Form):
    source = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    destination = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('results/', ResultPageView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('home/', HomePageView.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

edit 1

I have added my html code for the form as well

```
<form name = "form" action = "{% url "search" %}" 
    method = "POST" >{% csrf_token %}
    <div style = "max-width:470px;">
        <center> 
           <input type = "text"
              placeholder = "source" name = "source" />
        </center>
    </div>
    <div style = "max-width:470px;">
        <center> 
           <input type = "text"
              placeholder = "destination" name = "destination" />
        </center>
    </div>
    <button type = "submit" value = "Search" >
        <strong>Search</strong>
    </button>
```

Comment: Could you also add your the ```html``` file where you are doing search

Comment: Is your form action url pointing to the right url? In your urls.py, there is not url for the Search view

Comment: Yes, I have added the html code as well in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using *TemplateView*, an automatic GET method is implemented for both the pages. But the *search* function is actually trying to capture a POST request for *home.html*. Read this on when and when not to use *TemplateView*:

https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2017/12/when-and-how-use-django-templateview/

If I am correct, the *search* function is where you're rendering your form and it only allows GET requests. So it should be,

```
def search(request):
    my_search = SearchForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html',{"MYSearch": my_search}) # Render the form in home page

def results(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_search = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'results.html')
```

So you can get rid of both the *HomePageView* and *ResultPageView* class and set the URLs as,

```
path('results/', views.results, name='results')
path('home/', views.search, name='search')
```

Essentially, there is an even shorter way to do this, by combining both the functions into one i.e., render the form if its a GET request and view results if it is a POST request.

```
def search(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return render(request, 'result.html', # parameters to pass, if any)

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Then URLs would be,

```
path('results/', views.search(), name='results')
path('home/', views.search(), name='search')
```

It is described in the official documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

You also need to change the action attribute of form in the html file.

```
<form action="result/">
```

For a full-fledged example, check this out:
https://djangobook.com/mdj2-django-forms/

Comment: I tried your answer , but whenever I try to remove Homepage view, it shows error

Comment: Can you tell me whether the html form you have added above is in home.html or results.html?

Comment: It is home.html

Comment: So, the form is in home.html and you need to display that form data in results.html. Then why are you redirecting to */thanks/* ?

Comment: I started django yesterday, and tried redirecting to something else since what I wrote was not working, so tried something from django documentation that was redirecting to 'thanks

Comment: They redirected to thanks because they assumed the app has such a route.

Comment: Edited completely, check out